# Get current network utilization via /sys/class/net

Tags: linux, network-interface, monitoring, traffic

Playing around with some low level functions to monitor my system stats.

I would like to get the current network utilization the same way like I can get cpu temp

```
cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
```

or fan speed

```
cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon6/fan1_input
```

Looking at

```
/sys/class/net/my_network_adapter/
```

I didn't find a way to see the actual bandwidth consumption, rx_bytes just gives the total amount of data downloaded.

Comment: You want to monitor the traffic in B/s?

Comment: Yes thats what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the rate of B/s, no need of anything but your shell: Simply read rx_bytes file at each second and compare the current value with the value one second before.

```
rx1=$(cat /sys/class/net/wlp3s0/statistics/rx_bytes)
while sleep 1; do
    rx2=$(cat /sys/class/net/wlp3s0/statistics/rx_bytes)
    printf 'Download rate: %s B/s\n' "$((rx2-rx1))"
    rx1=$rx2
done
```

Of course, substitute `wlp3s0` by the interface you want to monitor.

Comment: thats a nice little trick, will try it, thanks

Comment: Here's a one-liner thanks to the example above for easier copy/paste into a terminal providing both rx and tx values: `iface=enp2s0; interval_s=3; dir=/sys/class/net/$iface/statistics; rxfile=$dir/rx_bytes; txfile=$dir/tx_bytes; rx1=$(cat $rxfile); tx1=$(cat $txfile); while sleep $interval_s; do rx2=$(cat $rxfile); tx2=$(cat $txfile); rxrate=$(expr $rx2 - $rx1); txrate=$(expr $tx2 - $tx1); echo "rx:$rxrate B/s (total $rx2 B) tx: $txrate B/s (total $tx2 B)"; rx1=$rx2; tx1=$tx2; done`, though I like the readability of Quasimodo's answer better.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel doesn't keep track of the temporal network interface stats - you have to calculate the values by yourself.

There are multiple utilities and applications which do that for you, including Gnome System Monitor if you're a Gnome user, then KDE has KSysGuard/Plasma Network Monitor/KNemo and many others.

Comment: ok this means I cannot avoid using one of the "bloated" tools - I really liked the idea of using the lowest level command to keep workload at minimum, similar to the already mentioned methods.

Comment: Speaking of bloat, there are console utilities to monitor network utilization as well: `iftop`, `ifstat`, `nload`, `bmon`, `iptraf`, `cbm`, `bwm-ng`, `speedometer`, `netload`, `dstat` and many more.